# Emulator not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

I just downloaded the SDK and tried to open the emulator but, even though the emulator showed, nothing appeared on the screen of it, also, the new hardware comes with a dual core, so how can I give my emulator two cores?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator takes a while to load. I know I killed it several times thinking it wasn't working. You just have to wait for it to finish loading. I don't think the emulators have support for dual cores yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a low dpi screen on your emulator, it may appear as though it is doing nothing. On a higher dpi screen, you see what looks like DOS characters saying "ANDROID" as it loads some background things. After a while, it will start loading the OS, and then you will see a logo on screen for any sized screen.

Don't know about the dual-cores, sorry.